# "to talk with friends" structure

Tags: translation, particles, particle-と

I tried to make "to talk with friends" based on 彼と話がしたい, so my try is this: 友達と話がする, but not only I'm not sure about this, but I also have some questions regarding its structure.

1.-Why that と? I studied that と means "and" and it can be used to make conditionals, so why is it necessary in the sentence 彼と話がしたい?

2.-Even if my attempt is correct, I have the feeling that it doesn't mean exactly what I want to express. Why using 話がする　instead of using the verb 話す?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Japanese.SE & +1 for asking a question with a good explanation of your thought process (rather than just asking _how do you say "to talk with friends"?_). I'm sure you'll get a good answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 「[彼]{かれ}と[話]{はなし}**が**したい」 is correct, but
>
> 「[友達]{ともだち}と話**が**する」 is incorrect.

This is because of the difference in the verbs -- 「する」 and 「したい」
The correct particles to use are:

> 「A + と + 話 + **を** + する」 = "to speak with A".  「**を**」 is the only possible particle to use here.
>
> 「A + と + 話 + **が or を** + したい」 = "to **want to** speak with A".  Both particles are possible (even though using 「**が**」 is more common).

Hope you are following me...

> "Why that と? I studied that と means "and" and it can be used to make conditionals, so why is it necessary in the sentence 彼と話がしたい?"

「と」 can also mean "with".  Some particles have multiple meanings.

> "Even if my attempt is correct, I have the feeling that it doesn't mean exactly what I want to express. Why using 話がする　instead of using the verb 話す?"

As I stated above, you cannot say 「話**が**する」.  It is 「話**を**する」 if you just need to say "to speak with (someone)".